# Java - Need to extend Applet, but already inheriting another class

Tags: java, inheritance, applet

I ran into a difficulty while doing an assignment for school. The problem is that the assignment requires us to create a class SummableSet that inherits from class IntSet, but I also need SummableSet to extend Applet in order to create an Applet that the Assignment also requires. I'm not sure how to go about doing this since I've done my research and it is not possible for a sub-class to inherit two classes. So how can I create an applet from these two classes if I can not extend Applet in my sub-class, SummableSet?

Comment: [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

Answer (score 2):

As you know, your class can only extend from one other class, and the solution is not to try to do the impossible. You'll need to create at least two classes here, one that extends Applet (why your teacher is having you use a dead technology like applets is beyond me), and the other new class that extends IntSet. Then the Applet extending class would use the other class in a "has-a" or "composition" relationship.

e.g..,

```
public class MyApplet extends Applet {
    private SummableSet summableSet = new SummableSet();

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // use summableSet here
    }
}
```

```
public class SummableSet extends IntSet {

    // ...... code for SummableSet here
}
```

Comment: and in order to create objects from other classes in a different file, I only need to include that file in the same directory right? Or do I have to import?

Comment: @sDetta: if the Java files are in the same *package*, then there's no need to import.

Comment: does that mean I have to include the package keyword along with name at the top of each file? That's what I'm getting from searching online but I'm not too sure.

Comment: And also, last question, when I am compiling should I compile all the classes involved or would it only be necessary to compile class extending the applet? I'm way more experienced in C++ and this is the first time I've had to implement more than one class in an assignment for my java class.